# Using Gen 2 CF instead of Gen 1 CF in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-cx

I'm new to this and I need some help with Google Cloud.
Basically, I was trying to create a project which uses many different CF and even works with DialogFlow CX.

The problem is that if I try to use a Gen 2 CF it gives me authentication problems if I set it 'Private'.

Is it possible to use the CF without setting that public or using a Gen 1 CF?

Comment: Can you elaborate the setting "private"? Do you talk about ingress or IAM permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can find good references at the [Securing Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing) documentation.

Basically, the default deployment is `private` which will require some sort of authentication (user account based or service account based -- more details on the doc aforementioned).

So, if I understood the scenario correctly, you just need to properly setup the `authentication` configuration and then your scenario of Dialogflow interacting with a Google Cloud Function service will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions 2nd gen uses Cloud Run, which changes the IAM roles required.
If the cloud function is in the same project-id as the CF 2nd gen. You can try to add "roles/run.invoker" for the Dialogflow Service Account. One way to add the role is to use this command at the cloud shell on the cloud function page.

```
gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding [FUNCTION-NAME] \
--region="[YOUR-CF-REGION]"\
--role="roles/run.invoker"\
--member="serviceAccount:[YOUR-DIALOGFLOW-SERVICE-ACCOUNT]"
```